# Moving a node around a path incrementally without using SKAction followPath

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to have a path that my node can travel around on demand.

For example, I want to have a circle in the middle of the screen and when i tap the left side of the screen, my SKSpriteNode will move in a counter-clockwise direction on the circle (and the same if i tap the right side of the screen).

From what I've researched, I can create the circular path using SKShapeNode, CGPathRef, or even UIBezierPath. Creating the path isn't the issue. In all the instances I've seen researching this topic, most people just use [SKAction followPath:path duration:1.0] and this makes the node go around the the circular path ENTIRELY in 1.0 seconds. I want to be able to tap left/right and only move incremental amount of space per tap. (If anyone's played Super Hexagon, think of the fluid circular motion of that game)

*Note: I only use a circular path as an example so I don't particularly need specific pointers on how to move around a circle per se, but more of ANY path of any shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can create any kind path shape you want using CGPath. This gives you the ability to create only the path for which you need to move your node. To use your circle example, create a 90 degree arc path and your node will move 4 separate times to complete a full circle.

If you do not want to use a path, you can also use the SKAction moveBy x,y,duration command. Tie a couple of those together and use them in a block sequence and you have yourself a generic path function.